# Arrayformula to number blank cells between non-blank ones from 0 to n

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to check an array/row,

1. ignoring non-blank cells (setting to `""`),
2. numbering empty cells from 0 to n,
3. resetting the number to 0 if the next non-blank cell is found.
4. stopping at the last cell

So, it'd look like this:

```
        A       B
 0  APPLE   
 1              0
 2              1
 3  BANANA  
 4              0
 5              1
 6              2
 7  CHERRY  
 8  DURIAN  
 9              0
 10 EGG
```

**A** is the original and **B** is what the function is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(ROW(A1:A11)-MATCH(ROW(A1:A11),IF(A1:A11<>"",ROW(A1:A11),),1)-1,"[<0];0"))
```

- `IF` to change all non blank rows to it's corresponding row numbers `1,,,4,,,,...`
- `MATCH` to get all previous row numbers filled down using approximate match `1,1,1,4,4,4,4,...`
- SUBTRACT the above array from it's corresponding row numbers and 1 `-1,0,1,-1,0,1,2,3,...`
- `TEXT` to change all negative numbers to ""

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A:A<>"", ROW(A:A), )))="",
 MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))), N(A2:A=""))-
 HLOOKUP(0, MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))), N(A2:A="")), MATCH(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(N(A2:A<>A1:A), ROW(A2:A), ), 1, 1),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(N(A2:A<>A1:A), ROW(A2:A), ), 1, 1), 0), 0)-1, ))
```

[image: 0]